# How to get the actual type of the parameterized types of a super's super interface?

Tags: java, generics

## Attention please: example here is based on an `InvocationHandler` instance, actually a `MapperProxy` instance from `mybatis-3`

---

Like this:

```
public interface A<T1,T2> {}
public interface B<T4,T3> extends A<T3,T4> {}
public class C implements B<Long, String> {}
```

How could I retrieve the actual type of `T2` of interface `A`?

```
((ParameterizedType)((Class)((ParameterizedType)((Class)this.getClass()
.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getRawType())
.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()`
```

Will only return `[P,E]`, however, `[String, Long]` is what I really want to retrieve.

Of course, here we can get actual parameterized types from :

```
((ParameterizedType)((Class)this.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0])
.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()
```

Here I can get `[Long, String]` for example.

But if parameterized types of `B` has different sequence and I do not really know what the difference is, how could I get the actual type of `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after long time of thinking and testing, a solution for this problem is coming.

---

The most important idea of this solution is **`B`'s type parameters will be passed as type arguments for `A`**

---

There are several key points to solve this problem:

1. Caching `B`'s type mapping of its type parameters and type arguments;
2. Trying to get `A`'s type arguments;
3. Retrieving the actual type arguments based on `A`'s type arguments;

---

In details for the former example:

1. `B.class.getTypeParameters()` => `[T4,T3]`
2. `B.class.getActualTypeArguments()` => `[Long,String]`
3. `A.class.getTypeParameters()` => `[T1,T2]`
4. `A.class.getActualTypeArguments()` => `[T3,T4]`
5. `A.parameterizedType[T1]` <= `B.typeArguments[T3]` <= `String`

After recusively doing this, the actual type argument can be get correctly.